# All Defined Platform Event Types Both Fail and Succeed Within the Same Hour

Tags: trigger, platform-event

I've defined a few platform events to capture changes in a few different object types across my environment, with triggers attached to each event that handle data transformations based on those changes that then write any additional changes back to each object. I'm only updating the record again if further changes are made in the transformations, and in testing too much recursive updating did not seem to be an issue. In fact, the system seemed to function fine for a few days.

However, over the weekend one of my users data-loaded a great deal of data without turning off triggers, causing us to hit the hourly limit of platform events just once. Since then, publishing for any kind of platform event has been failing, but with the PLATFORM_EVENT_PUBLISHING_UNAVAILABLE error, not the LIMIT_EXCEEDED error, and not all publishing is failing either, it's something like 1/10 of every kind of event publish fails among the other successful publishes and subsequent firing of their triggers. Debug logs on those triggers don't reveal any issues and they all read successful.

I've reached out to SalesForce support a few times with no success, instead hearing that because triggers are involved and that I do not have premier support I can't receive assistance with this. I've also removed a few of the platform events to reduce volume just in case, but the issue persists. I do implement retries for failures, but limited to 2 retries.

Is there another hidden limit that I'm hitting that I'm not aware of that would temporarily lock out the inserting of any new events?

Comment: when you query EventBusSubscriber, what do you see?

Comment: The docs for [PLATFORM_EVENT_PUBLISHING_UNAVAILABLE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_error_status_codes.htm) suggest the the service was unavailable and to try again. 
Since Salesforce support isn't helping out you may get a better response in the [Official: Platform Events](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004gjg) group.